# How to configure multiple entry point htmls with webpack/easy-webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin, aurelia

I am trying to port my Aurelia application from System.js + JSPM to Webpack. The app has multiple entry htmls: `index.html`, `index2.html`.

As I am new to Webpack, I started with [aurelia skeletons using easy-webpack](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/releases/tag/1.0.3), and tried to add my application specific codes gradually.

For the most basic case with single entry `index.html` the skeleton worked quite well. Also I added my local modules as `node_modules` and used the same in the `app`.

However, I am not able to setup the configurations properly for multiple entry htmls. This is what my `webpack.config.js` (showing the parts where it is modified) looks like:

```
const baseConfig = {
  entry: {
    'app': [/* this is filled by the aurelia-webpack-plugin */],
    'aurelia-bootstrap': coreBundles.bootstrap,
    'aurelia': coreBundles.aurelia.filter(pkg => coreBundles.bootstrap.indexOf(pkg) === -1),
    'some-common-script': path.resolve('src/some-common-script.js'),
    'index1-script': path.resolve('src/index1-script'), //needed exclusively in index.html
    'index2-script': path.resolve('src/index2-script') //needed exclusively in index2.html
  }, ...
 };

switch (ENV) {
  ...
  default:
  case 'development':
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
    config = generateConfig(
      baseConfig,
      ...
      require('@easy-webpack/config-common-chunks-simple')
       ({ appChunkName: 'app', firstChunk: 'aurelia-bootstrap' }),      
      require('@easy-webpack/config-generate-index-html')
       ({ minify: false, overrideOptions: { excludeChunks: ["index2-script"] } }),
      require('@easy-webpack/config-generate-index-html')
       ({
         minify: false, overrideOptions: {
         chunks: ['some-common-script', 'index2-script'],
         filename: 'index2.html',
         template: 'index2.html',
         }
      }),...
    );
    break;
}

module.exports = config;
```

The problems are as follows:

1. If I exclude `index2-script` from the default `config-generate-index-html`, then the order in which the scripts are added in `index.html` becomes `app.bundle.js, aurelia-bootstrap.bundle.js, ...`, instead of `aurelia-bootstrap.bundle.js, app.bundle.js, ...`, which causes `Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined...`.
2. As per my understanding that error is caused as `easy-webpack/config-common-chunks-simple` (wrapper around `webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin`) packed the initial, and common codes into `aurelia-bootstrap.bundle.js` ("bootstrap" chunk). Thus, I tried without `require('@easy-webpack/config-common-chunks-simple')({ appChunkName: 'app', firstChunk: 'aurelia-bootstrap' })` as well, but instead got

   - `Uncaught TypeError: Reflect.getOwnMetadata is not a function` from `aurelia-metadata.js`, and
   - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined` from `webpack:///webpack/bootstrap <hash>`, which seems to be raised because of a module is not found.

I am completely confused about what I should I try next. Please suggest.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: @MichaelTranchida I think I specified all the chunks that needs to be included along with using a sort function (alphabetically; source: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/481, and named the chunks accordingly).However, I am not currently using that, as having multiple entry points was resulting in much code duplication, and invalid states.

Comment: @MichaelTranchida The reason for having multiple entry points spawned from the need of avoiding loading all stuff, when those were not needed. However, with webpack all the chunks are compressed enough to load quickly. Along with that, if you are using Aurelia then maybe you can play with `aurelia.setRoot()` (in `main`) to navigate to multiple entry points. This is the solution I finally ended up with.